# Laravel translate json HTTP response message

Tags: laravel, http, laravel-5, localization

I have multilingual application using [laravel-5.4](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.4). I need to translate the ajax response of the HTTP header. I have the following message in the Arabic section:

> عفوا ولكن هناك الخطأ التالي:422 Unprocessable Entity مع رسالة خاصة تقول:

This an Arabic content and I want to translate the words "**Unprocessable Entity 422**" too.

I tried to modify the `$headers` array parameter of the [**json**](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_json) method like the following:

```
return response()->json([__('The status selected is not Equipment related status')], 422,['Status Code' => __('Any translable message')], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

However, setting the headers parameter like `['Status Code' => __('Any translable message')]` generates internal server error.

How could I translate that HTTP response correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution that I have done, is client-side solution. Withing the AJAX (Jquery) I use `str.replace` like the following way in the view `blade` file:

```
error: function(xhr, status, response ){

                    if ( status == "error" ) {
                    var msg = "{{__("Sorry but there was an error: ")}}";
                    statusText = xhr.statusText.replace('Unprocessable Entity','{{__('Unprocessable Entity')}}')
                     $( "#modal-body" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + statusText+ " {{__("With custom message")}}:<br> "+ xhr.responseText );
                     //console.log(xhr)
                    }
                }
```

By this way I replace the message using the Javascript string object's method `replace` to replace the English word with its Arabic translation `statusText = xhr.statusText.replace('Unprocessable Entity','{{__('Unprocessable Entity')}}')`

The HTML output of the above code is like the following:

```
error: function(xhr, status, response ){

                    if ( status == "error" ) {
                    var msg = "عفوا قد حدث خطأ: ";
                    statusText = xhr.statusText.replace('Unprocessable Entity','بيان غير قابل للمعالجة')
                     $( "#modal-body" ).html( msg + xhr.status + " " + statusText+ " With custom message:<br> "+ xhr.responseText );
                     //console.log(xhr)
                    }
                }
```